# Postsharp get intercepted method return type

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp, aspect

How can I get the return type of the intercepted method? I am writing a method level caching mechanism and I want to use postsharp to intercept the method calls. However,I need to be able to cast my stored object to the original method type.

```
 public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs InterceptedItem)
    {
        if (_instance==null)
            _instance = new CouchbaseClient();



        string Key = GetCacheKey(InterceptedItem);


        var CacheItem = _instance.Get(Key);

        if (CacheItem != null)
        {
            // The value was found in cache. Don't execute the method. Return immediately.
            //string StringType = (String)_instance.Get(Key+"Type");
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            InterceptedItem.ReturnValue = jss.Deserialize<Object>(CacheItem.ToString());
            //Type Type = Type.GetType(StringType);
            InterceptedItem.ReturnValue = (Object)InterceptedItem.ReturnValue;
               // jss.Deserialize(CacheItem.ToString(), Type.GetType(StringType));
            InterceptedItem.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
        }
        else
        {
            // The value was NOT found in cache. Continue with method execution, but store 
            // the cache key so that we don't have to compute it in OnSuccess.
            InterceptedItem.MethodExecutionTag = Key;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code. What have you tried so far? At which point of your code do you need to cast the cached object?

Comment: InterceptedItem.ReturnValue = jss.Deserialize<Object>(CacheItem.ToString());

Comment: Am I right that the `Object` in `jss.Deserialize<Object>(CacheItem.ToString());` is the problem? Why do you store the objects as JSON strings in the cache? Can't you just put the objects in the cache and avoid the serialization and deserialization?

Comment: Since I am using couchbase(NoSQL) I think I am limited to saving data as json objects. I tried storing the object in native format but when I do, the object doesn't store. I must say I am extremely new to couchbase so I am probably missing some storing options.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
InterceptedItem.ReturnValue = jss.Deserialize<Object>(CacheItem.ToString());
```

You could use the following code that allows to specify the type of the object at runtime (a generic type argument is determined at design time):

```
var mthInfo = InterceptedItem.Method as MethodInfo;
if (mthInfo != null)
    InterceptedItem.ReturnValue = jss.Deserialize(CacheItem.ToString(), mthInfo.ReturnType);
else
    InterceptedItem.ReturnValue = null;
```

You can retrieve a `MethodBase` object using the `Method` property of `MethodExecutionArgs`. However, as `MethodBase` is also used for methods without a return type (e.g. in case of a `ConstructorInfo`) you need to cast it to a `MethodInfo` in order to be able to access the return type.